# Oscillating disk performance

Tags: 14.04, server, hard-drive, performance, ssd

I recently upgraded my server from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. It used to run flawlessly for 2+ years, perfect in every way, but now I'm getting massive dropouts in the media streaming it provides.

So far the only issue I’ve been able to locate is that the disk performance is oscillating, BUT I'm in no way sure this is the culpit. The system has two disks, a 24GB SSD for the OS, and a 4TB HDD for data. Measured with “hdparm –t” both disk reads oscillate up and down between 2 MB/s – 192MB/s in intervals around 10 seconds.

Both disks pass SMART overall-health self-assessment.

The server is exclusively dedicated to running Logitech Media Server. Looking at "top", only 0.7-2.7% CPU is used on its dualcore intel atom when streaming the most demanding content (4.608kbps) with 9% memory usage (4GB available), so there should be plenty of resources, except for the oscillating disk performance.

Any suggestion on how troubleshoot will be most appreciated – and so will other suggestions on what might cause the server to stream data so unevenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the drives, or still more likely, the SATA control chips on the motherboard  are periodically overheating and protecting themselves by timing out rather than risking damage.

Ordinarily winter is not the season when I encounter overheating issues, but in this case it seems possible.  If you have an accessory fan you can direct at the motherboard, you could try that.  Also please examine it closely for accumulated dust.  Even a thin layer of accumulated dust on chips and heatsinks can represent significant insulation.

Comment: The drives are comfortable at 30°C and 42°C respectively, but the Intel NM10 Express Chipset is very hot indeed and while it’s made for running hot, just opening the chassis seems to restore flawless disk performance, so overheating may very well have been the cause – thanks!

Comment: This comment may seem bizarre to you, but as it is an ongoing project of mine and not one I intend to try to patent or profit from in any way, and it may be helpful to you, I thought now might be a good time to mention it.  I've been building PCs for over 20 years employing every kind of steel and aluminum case you can imagine, including rack mount.  All the while I imagined how I might do it myself for better cooling.  Last year I designed and built a convection cooled case out of pine.  Then two weeks ago I built a custom-duct-cooled case from a cardboard shipping box. Think about it.

Comment: Strangely it seem to work for a while, but the servers streamning performance still drops out even after installing both a heatpipe on the chipset and a fan, so I'm pretty sure it wasn't an overheating issue after all.

Comment: I changed the Ethernet cable from the server to the router and voila, now the system has been playing continuously for an hour - hopefully this was all there was to it!

Comment: I would not rule out that it could have been the cable, but that alone would not explain why removing the cover appeared to make it better.  I suspect you have what for over half a century repair technicians refer to as a "heat intermittent".  It is an intermittent fault which can be triggered by heat or vibration.  For all we know, the intermittent actually was at the ethernet connector itself, and changing the cable cleaned the contacts.  Whatever the cause I'm here to attempt to interpret your observations.  I doubt this is the last we'll hear of this problem.